# function with && and || comparing items within an array returns true, even outside the combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am making a tic-tac-toe with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. To the result verification, I am using two arrays, one counting the "X" moves, and the other couting the "O" moves with its id numbers. And an `IF` block, using `array.includes()` with all cases that are wins. But always this code return that "x won".

I tried this code

```js
function result_check() {
     if (moves_counter_x.includes(
         1 && 4 && 7 || 2 && 5 && 8 ||
         3 && 6 && 9 || 1 && 2 && 3 ||
         4 && 5 && 6 || 7 && 8 && 9)) {
         console.log("x won")
     }
}
```

I tried this code too:

```js
function result_check() {
     if (moves_counter_x.includes(1 && 4 && 7) ||
         moves_counter_x.includes(2 && 5 && 8) ||
         moves_counter_x.includes(3 && 6 && 9) ||
         moves_counter_x.includes(1 && 2 && 3) ||
         moves_counter_x.includes(4 && 5 && 6) ||
         moves_counter_x.includes(7 && 8 && 9)) {
         console.log("x won")
     }
}
```

But always this code return that x won. By example, when the the numbers on moves_counter_x are `[1, 5, 6].`
Why this function isn't working?

Comment: `1 && 4 && 7 || 2 && 5 && 8 || 3 && 6 && 9 || 1 && 2 && 3 || 4 && 5 && 6 || 7 && 8 && 9` checks if `moves_counter_x.includes(7)` - you need to read how [array includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) works

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand guy. Can you explain more?

Comment: To everyone who answered or is about to answer this question: This is clearly a dupe. VTC, please.

Comment: So sorry, I am just a beginner. I am trying to learn this. My english is bad too.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` and `||` are fully evaluated before being passed to a function, so `moves_counter_x.includes(1 && 4 && 7)` evaluates to the last term in the sequence to be evaluated (`7`, always, because `1` and `4` are both truthy, so `7` is the result of the expression), and you're *only* checking if `moves_counter_x.includes(7)`. You have to check the "includiness" for each value independently, and `&&` and `||` the *return* from `includes` together, e.g. for a simplified subset of your test, instead of:

```
moves_counter_x.includes(1 && 4 && 7) || moves_counter_x.includes(2 && 5 && 8)
```

you'd need to change it to:

```
moves_counter_x.includes(1) && moves_counter_x.includes(4) && moves_counter_x.includes(7) ||
moves_counter_x.includes(2) && moves_counter_x.includes(5) && moves_counter_x.includes(8)
```

There are ways to simplify this with other data structures and utilities (e.g. `some` and `every` methods combined with looping), but for a beginner, learn the basics of using the boolean operators correctly first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the logical operators inside the `includes()` argument, it doesn't automatically distribute. You have to call the function multiple times, and combine the results.

```
function result_check() {
    if ((moves_counter_x.includes(1) && moves_counter_x.includes(4) && moves_counter_x.includes(7)) ||
        (moves_counter_x.includes(2) && moves_counter_x.includes(5) && moves_counter_x.includes(8)) ||
        (moves_counter_x.includes(3) && moves_counter_x.includes(6) && moves_counter_x.includes(9)) ||
        (moves_counter_x.includes(1) && moves_counter_x.includes(2) && moves_counter_x.includes(3)) ||
        (moves_counter_x.includes(4) && moves_counter_x.includes(5) && moves_counter_x.includes(6)) ||
        (moves_counter_x.includes(7) && moves_counter_x.includes(8) && moves_counter_x.includes(9))) {

        console.log("x won")
    }
}
```

Comment: Very thanks! I understoood and its work now!

Answer (score 0):

The "and" operator does not combine its operands. Instead it returns the first operand if it is falsy, and the second operand otherwise.

Thus we have

```
0 && 3 === 0
1 && 3 === 3
4 && 5 && 6 === 6
```

When you write

```
moves_counter_x.includes(4 && 5 && 6)
```

It is identical to

```
// returns true because the array contains 6
moves_counter_x.includes(6)
```

What you actually want to write is

```
moves_counter_x.includes(4) &&
moves_counter_x.includes(5) &&
moves_counter_x.includes(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Use `Array::every()` to check whether each array item is contained in another array:
Replace `num1 && num2 && num3` to `[num1,num2,num3].every(num => arr.includes(num))`.

You can make your own `include()` function to check whether an array contains a set of values to have a similar syntax of what you tried. Note that `&&` logical operator provides the first truthy value if available or the first value if not. So you don't check existence of your operands since you check existence of the `&&` expression's result. You should pass them as separate arguments.

```js
const moves_counter_x = [7, 8, 9];
result_check();

function result_check() {
    const includes = (...args) => args.every(move => moves_counter_x.includes(move));
     if (includes(1, 4, 7) ||
         includes(2, 5, 8) ||
         includes(3, 6, 9) ||
         includes(1, 2, 3) ||
         includes(4, 5, 6) ||
         includes(7, 8, 9)) {
         console.log("x won")
     }
}
```

To go fancy you could put your moves into 1 array:

```js
const moves_counter_x = [7, 8, 9];
result_check();

function result_check() {
    const moves = [
      1, 4, 7, 
      2, 5, 8,
      3, 6, 9,
      1, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,
      7, 8, 9
    ];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i += 3){
      if(moves.slice(i, i + 3).every(move => moves_counter_x.includes(move))){
         console.log("x won")
         break;
      }     
    }
}
```